# Optimized way to filter values in Map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have map which has attributes associated with user for e.g.

```
user : {name=tom, address=usa, id=111, contact=7869989556, 
designation=engineer}
```

I will have list of rules which will block the junk users based on given key and list of values. e.g don't allow engineer whose name starts with test.
So My criteria would be if name = ^test.*$ and designation=engineer block from adding to DB.
Above rule can expand in future for other keys too and also with list of values. e.g. rule can be expanded for mechanics etc.

What can be the most optimized way to achieve this in java?

EDIT:

```
doNotAddUserCriteria = HashMap<String, List<String>>
```

Following is for engineers starting with 7777 or 99999, block them

```
doNotAddUserCriteria.put("name", ['^9999.*$','^7777.*$'])
doNotAddUserCriteria.put("designation", ['enginner'])

if(isValidUser(userData)){
    Process if valid else drop
}   

public boolean isValidUser(Map<String,Object> userData) {

    Logic should be applied here to check whether user is valid based on criteria
}
```

Also I should be able to apply selected rules based on config. like mechanics but not engineer and name starts with 7777 etc.
If I add like following , it will block both engineer and mechanics but that I dont want

```
doNotAddUserCriteria.put("name", ['^9999.*$','^7777.*$'])
doNotAddUserCriteria.put("designation", ['enginner','mechanic'])
```

Comment: A stream with filters, maybe? Post your data structure in Java, I mean like *I have a `Map<String, User>`* instead of *I have a map*... How does a `User` look? You can utilize methods of `User` for filtering and a lot of other options.

Comment: When you talk about optimized what's you want to optimize? Computation or memory? Because a possible way is create your own Map which duplicates data to achieve the best time getting penalized in memory

Comment: Agreed with deHaar: using a stream filter is probably the quickest way.

Comment: @deHaar I have edited the question with code and more details.

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow extension in the future a good way to implement it use a collection of `Predicate`. So you only have to add more predicates to the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MapFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User tomTheEngineer = new User("111", "tom", "usa", "7869989556", "engineer");
        User martinTheManager = new User("112", "tom", "india", "234234", "manager");
        User billTheTester = new User("113", "billTest", "spain", "23423423", "tester");

        List<User> users = Arrays.asList(tomTheEngineer, martinTheManager, billTheTester);

        List<Predicate<User>> allPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
        allPredicates.add(user -> !user.name.endsWith("Test"));
        allPredicates.add(user -> !user.designation.equals("engineer"));

        List<User> filteredUsers = users.stream()
                .filter(allPredicates.stream().reduce(x -> true, Predicate::and))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        assert(filteredUsers.size() == 1 && filteredUsers.contains(martinTheManager));
    }

    static class User {
        String id;
        String name;
        String address;
        String contact;
        String designation;

        public User(String id, String name, String address, String contact, String designation) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.contact = contact;
            this.designation = designation;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I didn't understand why you need a map, so I made a list. Feel free to change the data structure that better fits in your problem.